# Transformation of probability distribution function with step function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, density-function

Given a pdf  $f(x) = \lambda e^{- \lambda x} $, what is the pdf, $g(y)$?

Where
$$
y(x) = 
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{if $x<i$} \\
x-i, & \text{if $x>i$}
\end{cases}
$$

I tried writing the inverse function $x(y)$, however, $x$ cannot seem to be precisely defined when $y=0$.

Comment: i is a real constant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We assume that $i$ is a positive constant. Let $Y$ be defined by $Y=g(X)$ where $g(x)=0$ if $x\le i$ and by $x-i$ if $x\gt i$.

We find the cumulative distribution function $F_Y(y)$ of $Y$. For $y\lt 0$, it is clear that $F_Y(y)=0$.

For $y=0$ we have $F_Y(y)=\Pr(X\le i)=1-e^{-\lambda i}$.

For $y\gt 0$, we have $F_Y(y)=\Pr(Y\le y)=\Pr(X\le y+i)=1-e^{-\lambda(y+i)}$.

Note that $Y$ has neither discrete nor continuous distribution.

A similar analysis will deal with the case $i\le 0$. The details are a little different.

Comment: Can we convert this cumulative distribution function into a probability density function?

Comment: For the $y\gt 0$ part, sure we can differentiate. But there is a mass of $1-e^{-\lambda i}$ concentrated at $y=0$, so in the conventional sense there is no density.

Comment: I see, and how about $E[Y]$?

Comment: The mass at $0$ makes no contribution, so we just integrate $y\lambda e^{-\lambda(y+i)}$ from $0$ to $\infty$. We don't even need to work at the integration, since we are integrating $e^{-\lambda i} y\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$, and we can pick up the answer from knowing the mean of the exponential.